# Centre UImageView in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

i have a uiscrollview which i dragged using IB, i am trying to place 7 images inside the scrollview, right in the center of it, with some space to right and left, but so far i am unsuccessful. Can anyone tell me where i am wrong. [image]

This is the code i am using.

```
NSInteger numberOfViews = 7;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {

    CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.svIntro.frame.size.width;
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.svIntro.frame.size.width, self.svIntro.frame.size.height)];

    if(i == 0)
        [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"introScreen1.png"]];
    else if(i == 1)
        [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"introScreen2.png"]];
    else if(i == 2)
        [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"introScreen3.png"]];
    else if(i == 3)
        [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"introScreen4.png"]];
    else if(i == 4)
        [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"introScreen5.png"]];
    else if(i == 5)
        [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"introScreen6.png"]];
    else if(i == 6)
        [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"introScreen7.png"]];

    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

    [self.svIntro addSubview:imgView];
}

self.svIntro.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.svIntro.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.svIntro.frame.size.height);
self.svIntro.pagingEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: Did you added contentView (UIView) into ScrollView? after add all imageView into UiView.one more suggestion don't use more if & else if conditions use instead switch or put all image names into array & get it by index

Comment: I recommend to put them in a separate UIView, and then have that UIView as a single member of the scrollview. Or use a UICollectionView instead of the scrollview. As to your question why they are not centered, you should show the code / settings how you layout the views.

Comment: @DS Dharma:  no i haven't added contentView :S

Comment: @Kazmi thats problem add contentView & set constraints inside of scrollview.after add all other views inside of contentview.